# printing the data from database in java (printing from printer)

Tags: java

Through drawstring im able to print the data but in one column of database  the data is like a paragraph and in printed paper that data is coming in just one line but I want in paragraph format and not exceed certain point i.e take a new line

Any solution to printing Data is appreciated thank you

Answer (score 1):

You might be receiving the data for that particular column in the form of String.

You can use newline character i.e. \n to start from a new line while printing.

See the code below, lets say paragraph is the string I am receiving from database, now if I am printing it, It will appear in single line. After that I am putting a newline character after every 10 characters and printing the data:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String paragraph="Hello World. Welcome to Java World!!!";
        System.out.println("Before:"+paragraph);
        String formattedParagraph=paragraph.replaceAll("(.{10})", "$1\n");
        System.out.print("After:"+formattedParagraph);

    }

Output:- Before:Hello World. Welcome to Java World!!!
After:Hello Worl
d. Welcome
 to Java W
orld!!!
```